# List Feature Classes and use Update Cursor to calculate date values

Tags: arcpy, cursor

The basic premise is as follows: look in a folder and find all feature classes (within file GDBs), use a for loop to isolate feature classes one at a time and subsequently isolate date attributes, iterate through and update all the date-related attributes to a given value (currently set at 9/9/9999).

The code will run, but nothing happens. The print statements I have embedded won't even return anytihng.  I think the error is somewhere up at the beginning.

```
import arcpy
import os

try:
    def fcs_in_workspace(workspace):
        arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
            yield os.path.join(workspace, fc)
        for ws in arcpy.ListWorkspaces():
            for fc in fcs_in_workspace(os.path.join(workspace, ws)):
                yield fc


    for fc in fcs_in_workspace("path to folder of GDBs"):

        allFields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

        stringFields = []

        for field in allFields:
            if field.type == "Date" and "flex" not in field.name:
                stringFields.append(field.name)
                print(str(field.name))

        stringCount = len(stringFields)

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, stringFields) as curU:
            for row in curU:
                rowU = row
                for fields in range(stringCount):
                # change below to None or ''
                    if rowU[fields] == '':
                        rowU[fields] = "9/9/9999"
                    elif rowU[fields] == None:
                        rowU[fields] = "9/9/9999"
                curU.updateRow(rowU)

        del curU
        print("Updated Dates for " + str(fc))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + e.args[0])
```

Comment: If nothing's being printed then it's not entering the first `for` loop, meaning `fcs_in_workspace()` isn't yielding anything.  Add some print statements in there, make sure the folder path you're passing in is valid, etc.

Comment: There's a ton of reasons to use ISO 8601 formatting (e.g. "YYYY-MM-DD") for date strings [ob xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: I recommend removing try/except statements while testing and whenever you present code here because they can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the first part of your script. Maybe combining this with your UpdateCursor will help? I think you may be grabbing the fields wrong. Let me know if this works! If not, I can do some more debugging tomorrow. FYI the feature classes I was testing didn't have date fields, so I just called String fields instead, so you'll have to change that part of the script.

```
import arcpy
import os

try:
    workspace  = arcpy.env.workspace = r"FOLDER"
    gdb_list = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB")
    fc_list = []
    allfields = []
    stringFields = []

    for dirpath, dirnames, datatypes in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype = "FeatureClass"):
        for i in datatypes:
            fc_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, i))
        #print (fc_list)


    for feature in fc_list:
        field_list = arcpy.ListFields(feature)
        for field in field_list:
            #print(field.type)
            if field.type == "String":
                stringFields.append(field.name)
    print(stringFields)


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```